# Connecting to Linksys WRT54G router on Ubuntu

Tags: wifi, linksys

I'm trying to access my Linksys router from my browser via the address 192.168.1.1 but I'm getting the following error:

[image]

My router is on and connected to the internet, and I can access the internet from my computers if I connect them to the router with Ethernet cables.

Could the IP address to the Router have been changed? Can anyone help me access this router so that I can setup a wireless connection?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Someone voted down on my question. I wish I could know why.

Comment: This was closed due to it not satisfying the "in a professional capacity" clause of the FAQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you CAN change your default router's IP address and someone had done that. I reset my router's settings by pressing a tiny Reset button at the back of the router and then could again access the Router's Administration Page at 192.168.1.1 and configure my wireless network following these steps:

http://www.columbia.edu/acis/networks/aptnet/linksys/index.html